# Create different RootViewController instances depending on the target

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, rootview

I want to instance the RootViewController with different objects depending on the target I'm the running.

For example,

I have 3 RootViewControllers (RVCBase, RVCA, RCB) and 4 targets (T1, T2, T3, T4). I want that whenever T1 is running, RVCA shows as the RootViewController; when T2 runs, RVCB; and when either T3 or T4 is running, the RCVBase shows.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add define for exemple (T1, T2, T3, T4) with preprocessor macros. see build settings tab
You can handle in code with:

```
#ifdef T1
//do something
#elif T2
//do something
#elif T3  
...
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `[self.window setRootViewController:rvca];` to set the RootViewController for the window.

You will have to set for the target and then pass in the RVC you want.